# Deleting elements that appear only once in a list of vectors in R

Tags: r, list, function, loops, lapply

I have a list of 3 vectors, `X`, `Y`, and `Z`. I was wondering how I could **delete** elements that appear only once (here `ChandlerA` and `Trus.Hsu`) across all 3 vectors?

```
d = list(X = c(Bit.KnoA = 4, Bit.KnoB = 1, Bit.KnoC = 2, ChandlerA = 3, Ellis.etal =4, 
               Mubarak=5, SheenA=6,  Shin.Ellis=7 , Sun = 8, Trus.Hsu=3 ), 

         Y = c(Bit.KnoA = 6, Bit.KnoB = 3, Bit.KnoC = 4, Ellis.etal =1, Mubarak=2, 
              SheenA=1,  Shin.Ellis=2 , Sun = 1),

         Z = c(Bit.KnoB = 2) )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also use `duplicated` since you're only interested in the loner values:

```
nms <- unlist(lapply(d, names))
keep <- nms[duplicated(nms)]
lapply(d, function(x) x[names(x) %in% keep] )

#$X
#  Bit.KnoA   Bit.KnoB   Bit.KnoC Ellis.etal    Mubarak     SheenA Shin.Ellis        Sun 
#         4          1          2          4          5          6          7          8 
#
#$Y
#  Bit.KnoA   Bit.KnoB   Bit.KnoC Ellis.etal    Mubarak     SheenA Shin.Ellis        Sun 
#         6          3          4          1          2          1          2          1 
#
#$Z
#Bit.KnoB 
#       2
```

Answer (score 3):

We could create a copy of `d`, remove it's names so that when we `unlist` the names of the list names are not prepended to the vector. Count number of occurrence of each name in the list and select `names` of those who occur only once and remove them from original list (`d`).

```
d1 <- d
names(d1) <- NULL
vals <- table(names(unlist(d1)))
delete_names <- names(vals[vals == 1])
lapply(d, function(x) x[setdiff(names(x), delete_names)])

#$X
#  Bit.KnoA   Bit.KnoB   Bit.KnoC Ellis.etal    Mubarak     SheenA Shin.Ellis        Sun 
#         4          1          2          4          5          6          7          8 

#$Y
#  Bit.KnoA   Bit.KnoB   Bit.KnoC Ellis.etal    Mubarak     SheenA Shin.Ellis        Sun 
#         6          3          4          1          2          1          2          1 

#$Z
#Bit.KnoB 
#       2
```